# Systemd - Thunderbird - Start minimized without change of focus

Tags: fedora, systemd, startup, window, thunderbird

I start thunderbird after login, using sytemd service unit file for user:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Email Service

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=0
ExecStartPre=sleep 300
Environment="LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8"
ExecStart=/mnt/Data/opt/bin/thunderbird
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=EmailService

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Is it possible to start it minimized! I don't want to change focus to the Thunderbird window when it starts. Note: `--headless` CLI option is not suitable for this purpose.

---

OS: Fedora 38 (Gnome), Thunderbird 115

Answer (score 0):

It appears that without the help of external programs, this might not be possible.

1. Thunderbird itself doesn't offer any additional options for this purpose.

The following commands did not work, which were supposed to be an alternative to `--headless` like `--tray`.

`thunderbird --tray`

`thunderbird --tray &`

`MOZ_NO_REMOTE=1 thunderbird &`

`nohup thunderbird &`

`thunderbird &`

**Thunderbird always starts in the foreground.**

2. It also doesn't seem feasible through direct bash commands.

> Minimizing windows is typically a function of the window manager or desktop environment. In a standard bash environment, you usually don't have direct control over window manipulation.
>
> Starting Thunderbird or another program in the background without focus is typically not achievable through direct bash commands, as it is a function of the desktop environment. The startup behavior of applications can vary from one desktop environment to another and is often influenced by system configurations.
>
> To start or minimize programs in the background without relying on external programs, it may be necessary to use specific desktop-specific commands or configurations that can influence the behavior.

Other possibilities:

You can achieve this by using external tools like `wmctrl` or `xdotool` to manipulate the window after it starts.

- [wmctrl(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl)
- [xdotool - command-line X11 automation tool](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xdotool.1.html)
- [How can I run a program on startup, minimized?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/663187/how-can-i-run-a-program-on-startup-minimized)

The package `xdg-utils` contains the program `xdg-open`.

- [xdg-open(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open)

Unanswered questions:

- [How to start minimized program from linux terminal](https://superuser.com/questions/1403803/how-to-start-minimized-program-from-linux-terminal)
- [Bash - How to initiate GUI programs minimized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71921151/bash-how-to-initiate-gui-programs-minimized)